# Insert spaces before text in text box

Tags: ms-access-2016

I have numerous text boxes on an MS-Access form where I'm using left align, but I'd prefer to have a space or two between the edge of the actual box when it displays and the start of the actual data. I thought using the left padding item on the text box property sheet, but it doesn't seem to make any difference. I've tried using the format property like this:  "  " & fieldname but I got an error saying it didn't recognize the field name. I'd appreciate any help you could provide. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I set the property *LeftMargin* of a textbox from the default 0 to some value, the content is indented as expected by that value.

Comment: Thanks Gustav. I was trying to use the left padding but it didn't work. Setting the left margin property was perfect.

Comment: I've seen several answers on this site with checkboxes to indicate they helped solve the issue but with no upvote. If an answer is selected by questioner, it should automatically get one upvote. It will also help new users who may not know what the checkmarks are for. I upvoted this as it helped me with same question.